# How to get the row count using FMDB with SELECT statements and JOINs?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

This is my SQL to get the row count of OrderData.  Using straight SQL (in SQLite Database Browser) it gives me the correct value; when I use this select statement in my app with FMDB, I get a count of zero (0).

```
    //  get count of line items for each order
FMResultSet *rs2 = [fmdb executeQuery:@"select count(orderdata.order_id) from orderdata "
                    "join custdata on custdata.customer_id = orderinfo.cust_id "
                    "join orderinfo on orderdata.order_id = orderinfo.order_id "
                    "where custdata.Bus_name = '?'", globalBusinessName];

while([rs2 next])  {
    globalItemCount = [rs2 intForColumnIndex: 0];
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in the WHILE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is surrounding the replacement query with apostrophes.  They're unnecessary (and detrimental) when doing a query with an argument replacement, so you want to just end the `executeQuery` with

```
"where custdata.Bus_name = ? ", globalBusinessName];
```

My guess is that you're either getting a nil back for rs2 (which you should check for and then evaluate the error state), or the query is failing to find any results, and thus returning a valid rs2, but with a 0 count.

Comment: "globalBusinessName" has a space between two words... apostrophes are required in that case..

Comment: It Shouldn't be when it is being replaced as an argument in a statement.     Did you follow up on the nil return value and check the error?

Comment: Yes, I did... no errors.  The interesting thing is that I get the correct answer using SQLite Database Browser, and the SQLite shell tool, but not in the program, all using the same select statement.

Comment: Curious, which is why I think the problem is not with the select statement per se, but with the replacement using e variable.   Two other things to try if you haven't already: remove the where clause altogether and make sure you get a non-zero response; and try creating the query using a manually-generated string.  In other words use `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` to create your query and then pass that to `executeQuery` with no parameters.

Comment: Removing the where clause still gave me 0, should have been 2.  Using NSString gives the same result, 0.

Comment: At this point, I'd start stepping the query from `select count(orderdata.order_id) from orderdata` and add clauses until it fails.   I assume you already verified that the correct file is being opened.

Comment: Yes, correct file is being opened... your latest suggestion won't work because it has to have all the joins to get to the correct data, otherwise the result is always zero.

Comment: I understand that it isn't useful as a solution, but it would be as a diagnostic.